# Unable to choose specific database connection in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, sqlite

I have defined second `sqlite` connection in `database.php`:

```
'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'hamilton' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('hamilton.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use it like this:

```
public function beyondMapService($datasetName) {

        switch ($datasetName) {
            case 'population':

                $conn = DB::conection('hamilton');
                return $conn->select('select * from stats;');
```

I get an exception on `DB::connection` line, saying

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'Illuminate\Database\SQLiteConnection' does not have a method
>   'conection'

Why and how to use multiple databases?

**UPDATE**

My shame!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelt `connection` wrong, you spelt it `conection`

Answer (score 1):

It should be `connection`:

```
DB::connection('hamilton');
```